# Is there a way to define several types for a function argument with Python type hints?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a situation roughly illustrated below:

```py
from typing import List, Iterable, Iterator

class MyCustomObject:
    pass

class MyIterableClass:
    def __init(self, object_list: List[MyCustomObject]):
        self.object_list = object_list

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[MyCustomObject]:
        for obj in self.object_list:
            yield obj

class MyCustomObject2:
    pass

class MyIterableClass2:
    def __init(self, object_list: List[MyCustomObject2]):
        self.object_list = object_list

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[MyCustomObject2]:
        for obj in self.object_list:
            yield obj

# my_function could accept any Iterable[MyCustomObject]
def my_function(iterable: MyIterableClass):
    # This iterable could be Iterable[MyCustomObject], but the type checking seems to fail below
    for obj in iterable:
        do_something(obj)

my_function(MyIterableClass())
my_function(MyIterableClass2()) # This fails to check the type if I use Iterable[MyCustomObject] in my_function type hint
```

I'm aware that I can use Iterable[MyCustomObject] for that, but the type checking seems to break in PyCharm and does not raise any warning if I try to use the wrong type (e.g., a custom class that yields some other type).

So I am curious, is there a way to define several types as a type hint (i.e. List[MyCustomObject] and MyIterableClass) so the type checker works correctly?